# Filter by nullable datetime field using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to filter all rows in an SQL table that have a specific date. It works if the column is not nullable, but fails if it is.

This works for not nullable datetime fields:

```
ent.MyTable.Where(e => e.MyDate.Day == 12);
```

Obviously this works not for nullable datetime fields. After doing some search on the Internet, I found many "solutions" to this problem that look like to following:

```
ent.MyTable.Where(e => e.MyDate != null && e.MyDate.Day == 12);
```

Unfortunately this does not work for me either. And it is understandable why if I consider this error message:

> 'System.Nullable' does not contain a definition for 'Day' and no extension method 'Day' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I want to avoid fetching *all* SQL rows and then filter in .NET since I am only interested in a very small number of rows. Is there any other way that I don't see at the moment?

Comment: is `MyDate` defined as Nullable `DateTime` in your classes ? If so, your second line should not compile. If not, then your model doesn't match the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use value property of nullable date

```
ent.MyTable.Where(e => e.MyDate.HasValue && e.Date.Value.Day == 12);
```

Comment: Correct your answer, should be, `ent.MyTable.Where(e => e.MyDate.HasValue && e.Date.Value.Day == 12);`

Comment: @AdilMammadov `HasValue` and `!= null` are equivalent for Nullable types.

Comment: @Mostafiz fastest answer I've ever gotten! Thank you very much. I'll accept the answer asap :)

Comment: @user3185569 it was written like `e.MyDate.Value != null`

Comment: why downvote I have update my answer from sugesion, I have back in my original now

Comment: @Mostafiz, you are in a hurry, you returned to original version `e.MyDate.Value != null`. should be `e.MyDate.HasValue` or `e.MyDate != null` :)

Comment: It should be `e.MyDate != null`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 ent.MyTable.Where(e => e.MyDate.HasValue && e.MyDate.Value.Day == 12);
```